# Method for recursively calculating values from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

This question is somewhat related to hierarchial data but I already have a stored procedure from my database which is returning the data mentioned below. I am not trying to find out how to build a hierarchy (done), I am trying to figure the best way to calculate numbers based on that hierarchy with PHP (perhaps recursive arrays?).

Using a custom stored procedure, I am able to pull a list of sales representatives for our company, the products they sold and the "earn" percentage for each one of those products on new rows and their subsequent sales reps (if in a tree).

An Example of the data returned can be as follows:

```
Repnum | Name | productID | sales | earn | depth | parentRep
------------------------------------------------------------
1      |   A  |   1       | 5000  | 0.50 |  1    | 0
1      |   A  |   2       | 10000 | 0.35 |  1    | 0  
2      |   B  |   1       | 400   | 0.40 |  2    | 1
2      |   B  |   2       | 1000  | 0.30 |  2    | 1
7      |   E  |   1       | 30000 | 0.35 |  3    | 2
3      |   C  |   1       | 5000  | 0.33 |  2    | 1
```

It is safe to assume that the order of the data returned is already formatted and sorted appropriately based on the depth and information not presented here. In a Tree view, the data above would look like this:

```
1-A-1-5000-0.50-1-0
1-A-2-10000-0.35-1-0
   2-B-1-400-0.40-2-1
   2-B-2-1000-0.30-2-1
      7-E-1-30000-0.35-3-2
   3-C-1-5000-0.33-2-1
```

In my while(results) loop, I am trying to calculate the following for EACH repnum returned:

- The total of that rep num's sales multipled by the earn % for each product (their total sales and earn amounts)
- The total amount of sales for each downline tree multiplied by the difference between the current rep and the level below it

To show the math for how this would work:

### Rep 1 Earnings:

```
Rep 1 total sales = 5000 + 10000 = 15,000
Rep 1 earn on self = (5000 * 0.50) + (10000 * 0.35) = 6,000 hello!

Rep 2 total sales = 400 + 1000 = 1400
Rep 1 earn on rep 2 sales = (400 * (0.50-0.40) + (1000 * (.35-0.30)) = 90

Rep 7 total sales = 30000
Rep 1 earn on rep 7 sales = (30000 * (0.50-0.40)) = 3000*
(* the reason the earn is calculated at rep 1 earn - rep 2 earn is because in any tree, the "parent" can only ever earn the difference of his/her earn and the direct depth below him/her)

Rep 3 total sales = 5000
Rep 1 earn on rep 3 sales = (5000 * (0.50-0.33)) = 850

**Rep 1 TOTAL earn = 6,000 + 90 + 3000 + 850 = 9,940**
```

---

### Rep 2 Earnings:

```
Rep 2 total sales = 400 + 1000 = 1400
Rep 2 total earn on self = (400 * 0.40) + (1000 * 0.30) = 460

Rep 7 total sales = 30000
Rep 2 total earn on rep 7 sales = (30000 * (0.40-0.35)) = 1500*
(* here, rep 2 earns the difference between him/her and rep 7 because he is in the depth right above it / his/her parent)

**Rep 2 TOTAL earn = 460 + 1500 = 1,960**
```

... and so on

---

I could have built the script to use HEAVY mysql recursion and simply done a hefty number of while() loops for each depth but found it unnecessary and taxing on a system given the stored procedure I use to go ahead and pre-calculate the hierarchy and depth and sort the data appropriately. Calculating the top level rep is simple enough but to then go back from the 2nd person on the list (and so on) and start again is where I am struggling some.

I would like to be able to return an output similar to the following based on the sample data above:

```
num | Name | earnAmount
------------------------
1   |  A   | 9940
2   |  B   | 1960
7   |  E   | 10500
3   |  C   | 1650
```

Thank you ahead of time for any help!

Notes on questions that have been asked:

> Q: How are earn % calculated?
>
> A: They aren't calculated, they are determined by the rep the particular productID that rep is selling.

---

> Q: How are you determining "levels" or parent/child relationships?
>
> A: I am not in this example. This piece of the equation is taken care of through a MySQL stored procedure and in a lot of ways not relevant (I could also display the parent repnum for each rep but since the array is built from the top down, it likely is not too helpful). The depth and sort order of the example data in the first table is already formatted and laid out in a way such that each tree could be printed by a simple print(results_array) statement in PHP.

---

> Q: What is the relevance of productID in the first table?
>
> A: Each rep can sell any product available in our system (hundreds), classified by a productID. Each rep also earns a percentage of each sell for that specific product. The earn % is completely unrelated to a specific product type (though there are max and min earns for each product) or a particular depth (though a rep on a higher depth **never** has a lower earn % for a specific productID than his downline tree).

---

> Q: How is your data sorted in the first table?
>
> A: Somewhat irrelevant (just trust me) but behind the scenes I create a breadcrumb column which takes the current repnum, then appends children and sorts based on a combination of it and the depth of the tree at that point. Example as given:

```
0 (invisible parent which selects ALL sales reps)
  0-1
    0-1-2
      0-1-2-7
    0-1-3
...
```

---

Comment: Hm.. This is some form of tierd earning whre you earn a bonus for sales made by others that were brought in by you? How many different entries could be expected for instance for seller 7. Could he be on lever 0 as well as level 3?

Comment: How are your repnums linked to their parent? I see it in your tree but not in your results table at the top...? Is it purely based on the `depth` column and the order of the results returned?

Comment: @scrowler - through a parent ID but it is not necessarily required here as that information was already used to create the hierarchy table (including depths above). Although I *could* include the parent ID as well if needed, I dont think it is necessary since the results are given in order.

Comment: @JelleFerwerda - not bonuses necessarily, a tiered commission based sales program. Seller 7 can have as many entries as types of products he/she sold. In the tree above, he could never be above his parent's depth/level but if the "tree" was started with him, then yes I suppose he would be considered on level 0

Comment: Please add an example of the actual data sorted. Is it in an array? Or how would one know the level? I suppose a heavily nested array is wha you create?

Comment: @JelleFerwerda the example information above I give is the data sorted. The very first table details this. You know the level based on the depth mentioned. If it helps, again, understand the data is *already* presorted with level in tree format (level 1, then 2, then 3, then back to 2 and so on...)

Comment: Although the idea is pretty complicated, I got the most of it. One thing I don't understand is which `earn %` is being considered while calculating earn from a _child_ rep. In your example Rep 1 has two sales with `.50` and `.35` earn %. Why are you always taking `.50` into consideration when calculating earns on _child_ sales? What is the logic? Is it the first one, or the bigger one?

Comment: @matewka - I am not sure I understand your question. Rep 1 earns 50% on all  productID of 1, and 35% on productID 2. In the example, 50% is used on the total difference of productID1 and 35% for productID2 between him and his immediate downline. When comparing rep 1 and rep 7, only 50% is used because it relates to productID1

Comment: Now I understand. I didn't catch that detail before.

Comment: Maybe, an $key=>$value array $key being the RepID and $value being the amount up until now then in each itteration of your while(results) count the earnings of rep += his $value in array? then at the end of the while you have an array containing the repsID ($key) and his earning $value you can use to display on the page.

Comment: hm.. Confused. HOw is the data sorted? not by product, not by parent nor by representative?

Comment: Does'nt matter how its sorted as long as the "level" are correct it should'nt matter in what order sales are made.

Comment: @JelleFerwerda again, how the returned data is sorted is pretty irrelevant other than me saying "it is right". In more detail, the data is sorted by a combination of depth and "breadcrumbs" which I take the repnum and build out a string with downline repnums then sort starting with the highest parent and down through a tree created in a stored procedure. The example sort would be something I cant show in a comment but will list above in QA I suppose.

Comment: @JM4 - it's pretty heavy logic, I've just tried it out and there's a lot of foreach and ifs. It seems it would be much easier if you specified on each row who the **parent** was, so you could refer directly to it.

Comment: @scrowler - this is easily done. I can update above as such

Comment: Man, I can't stand when people vote to close a question without at least saying "because this question sucks". This is a Q&A forum people, be constructive if you think something should be closed/reworded/removed/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my approach.
I assumed that the array can be one-dimensional. `depth` is just enough to let us determine if a *Rep* has "*children*". So the array looks like that:

```
$reps = array(
    array("rep" => "1", "name" => "A", "productId" => "1", "sales" => 5000, "earn" => 0.50, "depth" => "1"),
    array("rep" => "1", "name" => "A", "productId" => "2", "sales" => 10000, "earn" => 0.35, "depth" => "1"),
    array("rep" => "2", "name" => "B", "productId" => "1", "sales" => 400, "earn" => 0.40, "depth" => "2"),
    array("rep" => "2", "name" => "B", "productId" => "2", "sales" => 1000, "earn" => 0.30, "depth" => "2"),
    array("rep" => "7", "name" => "E", "productId" => "1", "sales" => 30000, "earn" => 0.35, "depth" => "3"),
    array("rep" => "3", "name" => "C", "productId" => "1", "sales" => 5000, "earn" => 0.33, "depth" => "2")
);
```

I decided to take a recursive approach. We loop through the array in the `earn()` function, advancing the array pointer after each iteration. Inside the function we iterate again in a `for` loop starting from the `current + 1` array element to the end to find the *Rep*'s "*children*". The code looks like that:

```
function earn() {
    global $reps, $earns;
    $rep = current($reps);
    $key = key($reps);
    $immediateChildEarn = null;

    //basic Rep's earnings
    $earn = $rep['sales'] * $rep['earn'];

    //loop to find children with the same productId
    for ($i = $key + 1; $i < count($reps); $i++) {
        $child = $reps[$i];

        //we're only interested in Reps with the same product and deeper position
        if ($rep['productId'] !== $child['productId'] || $rep['depth'] >= $child['depth']) {
            continue;
        }

        //collect the earn of the immediate child
        if (null === $immediateChildEarn) {
            $immediateChildEarn = $child['earn'];
        }

        //the earn difference can't be greater than the difference between Rep and its first immediate child Rep
        if ($immediateChildEarn > $child['earn'] && $rep['depth'] + 1 < $child['depth']) {
            $child['earn'] = $immediateChildEarn;
        }

        //calculate the earnings gained from this child
        $earn += $child['sales'] * ($rep['earn'] - $child['earn']);
    }

    //just a quick fix to prevent throwing Notices - not significant for the algorithm itself
    if (!isset($earns[$rep['rep']])) {
        $earns[$rep['rep']] = 0;
    }

    $earns[$rep['rep']] += $earn;

    $finish = next($reps);
    if (false !== $finish) {
        earn();
    }
}

$earns = array();
reset($reps);
earn();
```

The results of `var_dump($earns)` will be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 9940
    [2] => 1960
    [7] => 10500
    [3] => 1650
)
```

Please, feel free to comment my answer. I'll try to repair any mistakes and improve the code the best I can.

*Complexity*:
I'm not good at calculating complexity of an algorithm but in my solution the complexity would be I think:

1. time complexity

   - worst-case **O(n logn)**
   - best-case **O(2n)**
2. memory complexity (not including input array)

   - worst-case **O(n)**
   - best-case **O(1)**

If I'm wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a closer look. Of note, your comment about the error in typing was not an error. This was explained in the * after it. A parent can **only** earn as much as the difference between him/her and his/her immediate child. In the example, 7 is a downline rep for 1 but the immediate child (and parent) of 7 is 2. 1 can never earn more than the difference of 1 and 2 because 2 will earn the difference between him/her and 7. Therefore the correct difference is 0.50-0.40= 0.10.

Also, the calculated earn for Rep 2 is off, as it only reflect his/her personal earn, not the earn from 7

Comment: I missed that. Well, it complicates the algorithm a lot. I'll try to consider this and edit the answer.

Comment: I updated the code. I hope now it will work exactly as you wanted.

Comment: Nice job. I decided not to have a go at it as I couldn't get the logic in my head. Was working on a similar approach.

Comment: @matewka - nevermind I see the issue. In my sample data above I had rep 7 earning 35% and your array has him earning 40% which would give rep 2 zero override earn. This makes sense. I'll continue comparing with my data but so far so good.

Comment: I'm trying to find out where the issue is but it is not quite right when comparing to my real data (in fact in some cases it is really off) and the script takes about 45 seconds to execute, sometimes longer. I will continue to investigate

Comment: Please, refer to my current code. There was actually a bug. After updating the function code I forgot to update the input array and final output. Now it's correct. Take a look, please.

Comment: @matewka - I corrected prior on that issue but I am running into errors in other areas. I am trying to replicate them with the simple sample data provided above to give output. Of note, why within the earn function do you loop the entire count($reps) for each iteration? Perhaps I am thinking wrong but it should only go down the tree until the existing child/rep depth is reached again. By this I mean, a rep can ONLY be a sub-rep for one rep so perhaps this could be improved on my end. I will see if I can reproduce the other error on my end. Perhaps best if we take on another thread?

Comment: @matewka - using a sub-section of actual data you can see what I mean here: `http://codepad.org/lHhI8n2q` - The very first rep (1-A) should have a total of 78.22 but instead is only calculating his/her personal sales and no downline figures added in

Comment: @JM4, when it comes to _earlier_ `for` loop break, indeed you're right. I'll fix it in the meantime. About your second comment with richer input array and `78.22` earn I noticed that. I'll examine the code, fix it and let you know. BTW, stack overflow always suggest to switch to chat on long comment conversations like this one, though I'm not getting the link yet. If you know how to do it, please open a chat for us.

Comment: @matewka - I figured out the issue I am facing at this point. I had not accounted for the fact that if a "parent" rep only had 1 product shown, it would not let his/her downline rep's sales be pushed up. I can account for this, it would simply need to show all available productID's for all reps and set sales/earn to 0 for those who have none instead of just the actual activity they do have.